# Nonexistent UITextfield name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

Hello I have problem with nonexistent UItextfield name. I had a bad text field name "userRoleTextFiled" so I changed it to "userRoleTextField" (in TeacherVC.h and Teacher.m and do new connection between userRoleTextField in TeacherVC.h and field in Storyboard), but now when I click on button, which link me to TeacherVC (VC=ViewController) and error is displayed:
[image]

I searched in all files in project, but I didnt found anywhere a text "userRoleTextFild". I tried clean simulator, clean product and than restart xcode. Without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mismatch between the storyboard/xib and the code.

You should:

1. Remove all links made between the storyboard and the `userRoleTextFild`/`userRoleTextField` property (or any other similar property).
2. Clean the project (cmd-k)
3. Re-add the link between the storyboard and the `UITextField` property.

Comment: I removed the UITextField and then I run the app with errors. Then I again added the same UITextField, run and everything works right..